# MVC Dropdownlist to Telerik MVC Dropdowlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I am trying to convert the following asp dropdowlist to telerik mvc dropdownlist.
I am using SQL stored procedures to popluate the list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="userName" name="userName" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="UserName">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HHNConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="GetUserName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/combobox) is what you're looking for I assume.  Are you asking how to rewrite your control with the Telerik control?

Well, first you don't specify the stored procedure with the MVC control.  You'll want to pass that in on your viewmodel.  Whatever you're using for database connectivity will be responsible for calling the stored procedure.

```
// Controller method
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // Pull user names from the database
    var users = _repository.FindAllUsers().Select(u => u.UserName);
    return View(users);
}
```

Then your view would look something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
    .Name("userName")
)
```

If you have a pre-selected user name, then you'll want to create an actual viewmodel class:

```
public MyViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the `@(Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName))` method.